# Replacing and updating the XML source in Lansa Integrator

Tags: lansa

In a solution in Lansa Integrator, I have an XML Binding where the XML format is still in flux. Most of it is fixed by now but minor changes are still expected.

With the SOAP Agent I could replace the WSDL - by creating a new solution with the same name as the old solution but referencing the new WSDL - and keep the bindings that already were set.

I have not found a way to accomplish this with XML Binding. I have tried the same as with the SOAP Agent - a new XML Binding with the same name - and I have tried editing the project manually in the XML Editor.

Is there a way for me to do this, so I do not have to recreate my bindings every time the XML format is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple, apparently: Within the same project group + group + solution group you create a **new** solution with the **same** name as the existing solution and of the same type (SOAP agent). Then you browse to (or add the URL to) the new WSDL.

Lansa Integrator then asks if you wish to overwrite the existing to which you agree.

Lansa Integrator will keep those parts that relates to the parts of the WSDL that hasn't changed, effectively making it an update.